# Detecting when a user is away outside of the browser

Tags: node.js, angular

I am building a "status" stand alone application customized specifically for my company.  In my app, a user will open the web site and update his/her status to one of several buckets (away, at my desk, out of office, etc) and THEN the user will most likely minimize the application.  My issue is how to detect when a user is away if they are not navigating within the status application browser window.  If a user were only navigating within the app, detection is easy-

```
 @HostListener('mousemove', ['$event'])
```

However, I need a solution where I can detect desktop inactivity and then (after 15 minutes) update the user status to 'away' in the database.

I am early in the development process, and am open to a different approach.  The technologies I am using is Angular 8, Node js API, and Postgres SQL.  Ideas?

EDIT:  From the comments, I understand that communicating with the desktop is not possible.  So at this point I am hoping on high level ideas on how to architect this while achieving similar results described in my post.  tcp/ip socket that updates user status from the api if the connection is broken when a desktop enters sleep mode?  Any crazy ideas?

Comment: You cannot record "desktop inactivity" from a web page in the browser. And even if you could, that doesn't necessarily relate to whether the use is at their desk or not.

Comment: You can't get such information in a web app for very obvious security / privacy reasons. This would require a desktop application and even then I'd hope you have some legal clearance for recording employee activity like that, some countries are not as relaxed about that as others.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*stand alone application*"?

Comment: stand alone = the application is it's own web site hosted on its own domain.

Comment: 10 years ago I worked on an application that did this; it was done as a native app with pretty low-level OS hooks to measure mouse and keyboard activity and time between.  Not simple.  Your "how do I architect this" edit will likely get this closed, because it's really too broad for SO.

Comment: Thanks for the replies thus far.  As Joe pointed out, I know this is a little broad.  A high level design idea is still the hope at this point.

Comment: you could use requestanimationframe, if the app is minimised it wont fire, in combo with websockets do a disconnect or check last check-in etc, update db status, if the client is not connected i.e computer is off then it wont have a socket open. which will pretty much cover all from away(app minimised),  at my desk (maximised/shown), out of office (no connection/app not up).

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Looking into this, and so far it looks very promising.  Will update if successful implementing it.  Thanks!